# Randomly generate numbers based on stock in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I need a bit of help with a script I am making in Php. Currently it is setup as a slot style game, where users can pay a bit of money and 3 random number are generated, each number links up to a prize they can win. Match 3 and win said prize.

Unfortunately as I will not always have every item in stock to give away as a prize I need a way to check through each number and make sure it is in stock:

`$stock = $conn -> query('SELECT DISTINCT ItemID FROM codes WHERE Available = 1');`

And if it is in stock add it in an algorithm which will randomly pick the 3 numbers. Currently I have a setup like so:

```
function generate_numbers(){
global $numbers;
$numbers = array(
'0' => rand(1,2),
'1' => rand(1,2),
'2' => rand(1,2)
);
display_numbers();
}
```

Which generates numbers based upon two variables and each number links to a prize. Obviously it does not take into account which numbers are in stock, which will lead to me giving out prizes I dont have, and it does not allow for an edge.

I need a simple way to check if an item is in stock and if it is stocked it is added to a list of prizes that can be won, I need it to have an edge so some prizes will appear (a lot) more frequently than others based on simple values like code X has a 0.25% chance of appearing and cody Y has a 50% chance of appearing.

If I set it up with a larger range of numbers:

```
function generate_numbers(){
global $numbers;
$numbers = array(
'0' => rand(1,100),
'1' => rand(1,100),
'2' => rand(1,100)
);
display_numbers(); }
```

---

```
if (($numbers[0] > 0) && ($numbers[0] < 40)){
echo "you win prize x";
else if (($numbers[0] > 40) && ($number[0] < 50)){
echo "you win prize y";
else {
echo "you win prize z";
}
```

I am still left either giving out prizes I do not have - or I could add a embedded if else to check if a code is stocked, if it is give it out and if it isn't either give no prize or give a default prize.

But this will mean that the more codes I have in stock the higher chance they have of being given which I don't want to do I really want it to be completely fair with predefined odds.

So hopefully all that makes sense it's not an overly complex problem but I think quite an unusual one.

Comment: Really interesting question :) I'm curious about other answers.

Comment: I hope you have a proper license to run gambling sites in your country

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scanning your question, I think you need to change your query

```
$stock = $conn -> query('SELECT DISTINCT ItemID FROM codes WHERE Available = 1 ORDER BY RAND()');
```

with this you pick the first 3 and you got 3 random prizes,

this is a quick solution. with chances its gonna be more complicated let me think...

**EDIT**

After some testing I think I got it,

You need top a add a column `chance` which is gonna be a number and the chance of that record appearing is then 1 on N,

The extra where code is:

`0 = FLOOR(RAND()*chance)`

so the final code is

```
$stock = $conn ->query(
    'SELECT DISTINCT ItemID FROM codes WHERE Available = 1 AND 0 = FLOOR(RAND()*chance) ORDER BY RAND()'
);
```

Comment: I think you're onto something here I have pasted the code into my query and added the chance section with variables in each, but I am not entirely sure what the `0 = FLOOR(RAND()*chance)` does. It seems to effect the database and make items with the lower chance value ie 0.25 show up more often than numbers with a high chance ie 100

Comment: @LukeWatson what the?

Comment: like I said, if chance is 100, it will appear 1 time in the 100 times, if chance is 2 it will appear 1 time in the 2 times it `RAND()` returns a random number between 0 and 1 I multiply that by `chance` and then floor it and if it's 0 it will be chosen, and yes `chance` is an odd name, couldn't think of a different one

Comment: Ah I see that makes sense, thank you :) I will have to edit some tables to make it work but I think this is the best solution, I will have a chance on each item and if no items appear then the default will be no prize (currently the no prize chance is defined in the table along with other prizes)

Comment: @LukeWatson Welcome, I hope it does what you want and yes there will be automatically be an no prize, but if you got much items there is a chance that there will always be prize :)

Comment: @LukeWatson also if you think this is the best solution you can click the grey bordered check mark to mark your question as answered and mark my answer as best solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you might begin with creating an array of available prizes with the query in beginning.

So the array would be:

```
{0 => prize1_id,
 1 => prize3_id,
 2 => prize4_id,
 // ...and so on
 }
```

Then you can take random numbers but not from the prizes ids, but array indices (keys).

If you want some items have more chance to be chosen, you can add them twice for example.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this (if you don't have very many items) is to create an array of the `ItemID`s and use `shuffle()` on the array.  Then select the first three elements ( or randomize this selection with `rand()` or `mt_rand()`) to be the numbers you display.  This way you can pick items that do not exist.  You can alter this algorithm to check stock levels so that it doesn't add an `ItemID` with no or low stock as you decide (may be via a new column in `codes` that defines the minimum stock required for the item to be chosen).

To get the edge you can add a number of duplicate `ItemID`s for items that you want to be selected more often.  You can add another column to the `codes` table to indicate the number of times you want to include a particular item, so with a minimum of 3 (to match three numbers) you can assign an larger values for for `ItemID`s that you want to be picked more often by the algorithm.  It also has the possibility of putting 0 for items you don't want to give away.